# Removing horizontal gap between image tags HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I was just practicing HTML and CSS and I ran into an annoying problem. I am wondering what is that horizontal gap and how to remove it?

Thanks in advance

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Practice</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
      <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
      <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding" />
      <style>
         html,body
         {
         margin:0; padding:0; height:100%;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <script src="./js/jQuery.js"></script>

      <img id="sample-img" src="Green-Nature-wallpaper.jpg" style="margin:0; padding:0;"></img>
      <img id="sample-img2" src="Green-Nature-wallpaper.jpg" style="margin:0; padding:0;"></img>
      <script>
         $( document ).ready(function () {
            $("#sample-img").width($(window).width());
            $("#sample-img").height(0.6*$(window).height());
            $("#sample-img2").width($(window).width());
            $("#sample-img2").height(0.6*$(window).height());
         });
         $(window).resize(function() {
            $("#sample-img").width($(window).width());
            $("#sample-img").height(0.6*$(window).height());
            $("#sample-img2").width($(window).width());
            $("#sample-img2").height(0.6*$(window).height());
         });
      </script> 
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you see when you debug in the browser?

Comment: @ElGavilan Nothing, Empty..

Comment: its the whitespace between the images. make them display block.

Comment: Are you sure the actual images don't contain extra margins themselves?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried setting the image margin and padding to 0?

```
<style>
    img {
        position:relative;
        display:block;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: This works but is not necessarily the answer. It changes the default inline style of images to block. That can be OK but may cause undesired effects depending on the context.

Comment: It depends on if the page uses other images. If it does he can simply assign a class to the images he wants displayed as block and keep the other ones to their default CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Images are inline content, just like words or individual characters. Images are aligned to the baseline where characters are placed. Add `vertical-align:bottom` to the image CSS. Images are inline elements and placed similarly to text and what you are seeing is the gap reserved for descenders of text fonts like the lower curl of the letter 'g'.